# Why 100% height does not make canvas to extend to the bottom of the div?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

Here is my code & html markup:

```js
$(document).ready(render)


function render() {

  wl = [['hello', 12], ['dear', 10], ['a', 9], ['Joe', 5], ['8', 2]];

  $canvas = $('.wordcloud-canvas')[0];
  
  $canvas.width  = $canvas.offsetWidth;
  $canvas.height = $canvas.offsetHeight;

  
  options = {
    list           : wl,

    weightFactor   : 12,
    color          : '#f02222',
    rotateRatio    : 0,
    rotationSteps  : 0,
    shuffle        : false,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    drawOutOfBound : false,
    gridSize       : 16
  };
    
  window.WordCloud($canvas, options);
  
}
```

```css
.wordcloud-view {
  display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.wordcloud-container {
  display: block;
  border: 1px blue solid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 700px;
}

.wordcloud-canvas {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px green solid;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wordcloud2.js/1.0.6/wordcloud2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wordcloud-view">
  <div class="wordcloud-container">
   <canvas id="wordcloud-canvas" class="wordcloud-canvas"></canvas>
  
  <div></div>
</div></div>
```

What I don't understand is why the canvas does not extend vertically despite `height: 100%`

As you can see in the screenshot,

[image]

if the canvas is fully extended, I would see the green border more of less overlaps the blue border.

Why it does not happen? I have tried different `position` and `display` settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Height percentages only work when all parent elements also have a defined height.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height
>
> **The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the**
>   **generated box's containing block**. If the height of the containing
>   block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content
>   height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the **value
>   computes to `auto`**

In your case simply make html,body have defined height, for example:

```
html,body {
  height:100%;
}
```

Demo

```js
$(document).ready(render)


function render() {

  wl = [['hello', 12], ['dear', 10], ['a', 9], ['Joe', 5], ['8', 2]];

  $canvas = $('.wordcloud-canvas')[0];
  
  $canvas.width  = $canvas.offsetWidth;
  $canvas.height = $canvas.offsetHeight;

  
  options = {
    list           : wl,

    weightFactor   : 12,
    color          : '#f02222',
    rotateRatio    : 0,
    rotationSteps  : 0,
    shuffle        : false,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    drawOutOfBound : false,
    gridSize       : 16
  };
    
  window.WordCloud($canvas, options);
  
}
```

```css
html,body {
  height:100%;
}
.wordcloud-view {
  display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.wordcloud-container {
  display: block;
  border: 1px blue solid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 700px;
}

.wordcloud-canvas {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px green solid;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wordcloud2.js/1.0.6/wordcloud2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wordcloud-view">
  <div class="wordcloud-container">
   <canvas id="wordcloud-canvas" class="wordcloud-canvas"></canvas>
  
  <div></div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: So it is likely this problem is  just specific to code-snippet? I suppose default css of `body` in most browsers is `100%`?

Comment: Also the rule does not apply to width, right? It seems inconsistent

Comment: No, body and html do not have a set height by default, so it is `auto` hence why you need to set it. As for width any element with a `display` of `block` element is 100% width unless otherwise set. It changes depending on display's value. inline elements for instance does not have a set width.